# My a:hover is not working for some reason

Tags: css, html

Not sure why it's not working, but here's my code.

```
 .tm-nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;}

 .tm-nav ul li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none; 
 font-family: Trebuchet MS;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 color: #8e7e6b;
 }

 .tm-nav a:hover: {
  color: black;}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
     <nav class="tm-nav">
                 <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </nav>
```

Whenever, I hover over my navigation links, they don't change color, even adding text-decoration: underline under a:hover does not take effect.

Comment: Your code is currently malformed, you can see the `insert code here` placeholder provided by Stack Overflow. You may want to fix this for better legibility.

Comment: maybe the `:` after hover?

Comment: There is a great answer right below. Why not accept?

Answer (score 4):

```
.tm-nav a:hover: {
  color: black;}
```

should be

```
.tm-nav a:hover {
  color: black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra colon sitting on ".tm-nav a:hover {}"

I removed the colon and tried it on my computer and it worked.